# Can I tell if a frame access will be cross-domain before performing it?

Tags: javascript, webkit, cross-domain, safari-extension

I am trying to find the DOM `iframe` or `frame` element for each of the frames in a window's `frames` collection. The fastest way to do this, I think, is to access the frame's `frameElement` property. This property is only available for a same-domain access, and returns undefined and prints an error message to the log in the cross-domain case.

I can loop through the elements returned from `document.getElementsByTagName` to find the correct element in the cross-domain case, but I'd like to avoid printing the "Unsafe JavaScript attempt" message to the log.

Is there any way to tell before trying it if a property access attempt will run afoul of the cross-domain security policy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the domain on the url of the hosting page and the frame (src property). If the domains differ, you will most likely get an error.

I say most likely because if the frame is on a subdomain, but has specified `document.domain` to be the same as the parent frame, then cross-domain access will work.

Comment: Is there any standard way to parse the src property? I tried checking the frame's location property but that triggered the cross-domain error.

Comment: @Greg: Not as far as I know. But use some regexp like mentioned at http://w3guru.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url-using.html and compare the strings.

Comment: Won't that also fail if the user follows a link in the frame to another site, so the src and the frame's contents no longer match?